# Is ajaxComplete() guaranteed to run after any DOM updates?

Tags: jquery, ajax, race-condition, dom-manipulation

JQuery's [`ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) lets me run my own Javascript after an AJAX  request completes.

However, when manipulating DOM elements in an `ajaxComplete()` handler, I sometimes have observed strange problems, which look like the DOM changes caused by the AJAX request are not complete.
In other words, it looked like there was a race condition between the DOM updates by the AJAX request and the `ajaxComplete()` handler.

Unfortunately, I could not find anything definite about this in the JQuery docs. Thus my question:

Is a race condition between AJAX request and handlers possible? Or does JQuery guarantee that `ajaxComplete()` handlers will only run after all DOM updates from the AJAX request are done?

---

For example, in this [forum thread](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17143&sid=9f659510f6270ba2704cfd6b84712e6f) someone claims:

> Regarding execution order. The execution order in PrimeFaces is
>
> 1) onsuccess / onerror callbacks 2) DOM update 3) oncomplete callback
>
> Complete is a function to be called when the request finishes, after
>   success and error callbacks were executed and DOM was updated. But
>   keep in mind, DOM update can takes some time and not be finished in
>   oncomplete

This seems to indicate that `oncomplete` callback (which is implemented using JQuery's `ajaxComplete()`) will run concurrently with the DOM update. Or is this a misunderstanding?

Comment: I believe it's referring to the fact that images may not be done loading yet. You can be sure that the elements at least have been inserted into the dom.

Comment: @KevinB: "You can be sure that the elements at least have been inserted into the dom." That sounds like the information I was looking for. Would you consider expanding that with another sentence or so and making it an answer?